# What program will display live stock quotes in the top bar?

Tags: 12.04, appmenu

Hello! My question is about the stock market! I am trying to find a program that will display stock quotes on the top bar of ubuntu! By default in 10.10 Maverick Meerkat Ubuntu you had the ability to add applications from the top bar, like cpu process, weather actives, automatic events. I don't understand why this was access was taken out, should of been added by default toward Ubuntu! What is your advice toward a program that will display stock quotes in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS! If you have any knowledge, advice, comment. I would apperciate it!
Thanks
Ubuntu Community

Answer (score 0):

[plasma-widget-stockquote](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/banshee) [image: Install plasma-widget-stockquote]

> Displays stock quotes on the desktop pulled from the yahoo servers.

[image]

[It is a KDE plasma widget](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Stock+Quote?content=90695).

Oh and in case you want it answered: Ubuntu switched from gnome to unity and that means the top bar is fairly locked to what it can do. Plasma widgets are a good looking alternative.

Comment: I will try it out and see if it works with my system! Thank You Anyway :)